# VPN connection with different destination and source port without SSH tunnel

Tags: openvpn, port-forwarding, softether

We run a little webserver with a web GUI but more and more confidential data is being stored on it. So we setup a little OpenVPN Server. In the last couple of months we have been facing more and more difficulties to connect to the server due to stricter http and https proxys.
So the only chance I see is to encapsulate it better in another protocol. As we still run our web server on port 80 and the fact that port 80 and 443 are usually open I will try to setup OpenVPN to run over HTTP but I would like to use a different port on the server site, e.g. 8080 so the connection would be
CLIENT.....-> SERVER
1.2.3.4:80 -> 5.6.7.8:8080

My question, is that possible as I find only resources setting up the server to listen at port 80?
I'm aware of OpenVPN'w sharing port feature but I would like to avoid it to keep server's response time etc low.

In addition [I've learned](https://serverfault.com/questions/163768/vpn-through-only-http/815723#815723) that depending how the HTTP VPN connection is established you are not able to establish a tunnel as some proxys don't allow http CONNECT requests. Is that still a problem with OpenVPN as I can only find very old post about it talking about at all?

I've also started reading into [SoftEther VPN](https://www.softether.org/) but I cannot asset if it's really equivalent or better alternative as I cannot find that much independent information.

Answer (score 0):

1) When initiating the connection to the outer service, clients aren't eligible to chose the source port, it's chosen by the OS IP stack, and it's chosen randomly from the range 1025-65535. So if the key point of this question is the client connecting from port 80, then you will not get this.

2) Furthermore I doubt that originating the connection from port 80 will help you, because most firewalls and IDSes look on the destination side, not on the source.

Comment: **1)** what do you mean by  OS IP stack, is the same as explained [here](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/5769).     
So connection is: 1.2.3.4:RANDOM range 1025-65535 -> 5.6.7.8:80 or 5.6.7.8:443.

**2)** `most firewalls and IDSes look on the destination side` thanks for that piece of information, so the port of the server have to move if OpenVPN worsen webserver's response time.

Comment: can you say anything about  SoftEther VPN and http CONNECT requests?